# How to make Libgdx particles not be affected by background color?

Tags: java, colors, libgdx, particles

I'm using libgdx particle editor to make my particle effects, and I noticed that when the background is black everything is fine but when the background isn't black, or if I render the particle in front of a sprite the particle color is affected.

**with black background**

[image: with black background]

**with colored background**

[image]

initialization:

```
ParticleEffect effect = Pools.obtain(ParticleEffect.class);
        effect.load(Gdx.files.internal("effects/myEffect.p"), Gdx.files.internal("effects"));
        effect.setPosition((pos.x - 0.3f) * 30, (pos.y - 6) * 30);
        effect.start();
```

rendering:

```
effect.draw(batch, Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime())
```

What I'm trying to do is render the particles with its original color even if the background isn't black. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting additive to false on the particle emitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, with the editor has an option called "*aditive*" that is well down, disable it and will have particles with alpha **1**.